GOOGLE APP SCRIPT - How to prevent 2 functions each activated by a specific button to run in the same time?
I have in a single script 2 functions.
function a(){
//}
function b(){
//}
Each function is activated by a separate button in my spreadsheet.
Point is, the 2 functions must not run in the same time because it could create issues in my spreadsheet.
There will be many users at the same time working on the spreadsheet and both buttons could be pushed at the same time or repeatedly.
Glad if you have a hint !
M
Have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.
Especially lock class of app script and a few others ideas.

Don't include tags in the title

Do you need to build a pending execution queue or just deny the execution?

Found this previous question that could help:
check if a trigger execution is currently running in Google Apps Scripts
But an easy workaround would have to store the info into a hidden cell?
When function starts, you could write in a cell "A function is running", when the process is done update the value to "No function running". And then add a condition in the beginning of your functions to check if something is running...
Just a thought!
